# tex4ht and listings: lines don't break when using escapeinside

Tags: listings, tex4ht

This is the first I'm posting a question. So, I hope I don't do anything wrong.

I've tried to get HTML from my latex document by using tex4ht. For cross-referencing within the lstlisting environment, I defined an escapeinside expression. My MWE is this. The code is written down in the file `mwe.tex`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    escapeinside={(@/}{/@)}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}  
First line (@/\label{Ref1}/@)  
Second line (@/\label{Ref2}/@)  
Third line (@/\label{Ref3}/@)  
\end{lstlisting}

Reference to line \ref{Ref1}, \ref{Ref2}, and \ref{Ref3}.
\end{document}
```

When generating a PDF with pdflatex, everything is fine. In particular, there are line breaks after each line in the lstlisting environment.

```
First line
Second line
Third line

   Reference to line 1, 2, and 3.
```

However, when I use *htlatex mwe* for getting the HTML, the line breaks are missing.

The HTML output looks like

```
 First line         Second line Third line 
   
   Reference to line 1, 2, and 4.
```

Why is the last reference pointing to line 4, whereas in the PDF, it is referred to line 3? And how can I tell tex4ht to break the lines similar to the PDF file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MWE produces the expected result on my machine (html page with correct line breaks and correct reference numbers). Do you get any warnings from htlatex/tex4ht on the command line or in the log? What is your version of pdfTex, tex4ht, lstlisting? Which web browser/OS are you using?